# Angular external templating vs Handlebars external templating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery, templates, handlebars.js

this is how I load and compile my templates in Handlebarsjs,

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'handlebars'
],
function ($, Handlebars) {

    // @reference: http://berzniz.com/post/24743062344/handling-handlebars-js-like-a-pro
    Handlebars.getTemplate = function(name) {
        if (Handlebars.templates === undefined || Handlebars.templates[name] === undefined) {
            $.ajax({
                url : 'js/template/' + name + '.handlebars',
                success : function(data) {
                    if (Handlebars.templates === undefined) {
                        Handlebars.templates = {};
                    }
                    Handlebars.templates[name] = Handlebars.compile(data);
                },
                dataType: "text",
                async : false
            });
        }
        return Handlebars.templates[name];
    };

    // Precompile your templates and add/paste them below here. 

});
```

and I can just retrieve the template with this line below,

```
this.$el.html(Handlebars.getTemplate('list')({contacts: response}));
```

So this I don't have to use ajax to call the same template over and over again. I can just get it from the Handlebars' storage.

Is this possible with Angularjs? I have been looking up for tutorials for doing this in Angualrjs but can't find any. Any ideas where is the good start?

Answer (score 1):

Angular.js caches templates when they are requested (so the request only happens once), but you can prepopulate that cache using [`$templateCache`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24templateCache).